# How to sort test grades by letter grade

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

top 20% of all scores is an A.
second 20% of scores is a B.
third 20% of scores is a C.
fourth 20% of scores is a D.
bottom 20% of scores is an F.

the following scores:

```
99, 92, 91, 91, 89, 85, 83, 82, 80, 79, 78, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 62, 55, 43,
20
```

I need to write a function that takes a score list of any length (not necessarily the list used as an example above) as a parameter, and returns the list of grades associated with those scores.

So far what I got is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button sort out grades.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="testScores"></p>
<p id="top"><p>
<p id="second"><p>
<p id="third"><p>
<p id="fourth"><p>
<p id="bottom"><p>

<script>
var grades = [89, 92, 20, 91, 99, 85, 83, 82, 77, 62, 78, 78, 80, 76, 75, 43, 72, 55, 74,
    91];
document.getElementById("testScores").innerHTML = grades;    

function myFunction() {
    grades.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    document.getElementById("testScores").innerHTML = grades;
    document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = grades;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = grades;
    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = grades;
    document.getElementById("fourth").innerHTML = grades;
    document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = grades;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am able to get it to descend from greatest to least, and have individual lines for each row (A,B,C,D,F). I cannot figure out how to get the grades distributed by increments of 20%.

```
I want the output to be:
A=99,92,91,91
B=89,85,83,82
C=80,79,78,78
D=77,76,75,74
F=62,55,43,20
```

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment.

Comment: Haha I wish it was. Then i'd be able to ask a teacher for help. This is actually something that my friend wanted to implement. He just got his teaching license here in Massachusetts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this,

```js
var grades = [89, 92, 20, 91, 99, 85, 83, 82, 77, 62, 78, 78, 80, 76, 75, 43, 72, 55, 74,44,
    91];
document.getElementById("testScores").innerHTML = grades;    

function myFunction() {
    grades.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    document.getElementById("testScores").innerHTML = grades;
    var slice = Math.ceil(grades.length * 0.2), init = 0;
    
    document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = grades.slice(init, init+slice);
    init+=slice;
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = grades.slice(init, init+slice);
    init+=slice;
    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = grades.slice(init, init+slice);
    init+=slice;
    document.getElementById("fourth").innerHTML = grades.slice(init, init+slice);
    init+=slice;
    document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = grades.slice(init, init+slice);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button sort out grades.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>

<p id="testScores"></p>
<p id="top"><p>
<p id="second"><p>
<p id="third"><p>
<p id="fourth"><p>
<p id="bottom"><p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I implement a Math.ceil() so I can make sure floats work too?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to create a groupByPercentile function. This takes two arguments (can make it take one, but this is more reusable) and returns an object of grades, each one containing an array of the scores.

```
function groupByPercentile (sortedArray, percent) {
  var group = {
    "A": [],
    "B": [],
    "C": [],
    "D": [],
    "F": []
  };

  var percentile = sortedArray.length * percent;

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
    if (group["A"].length < percentile ) { group["A"].push(sortedArray[i]); continue; };
    if (group["B"].length < percentile ) { group["B"].push(sortedArray[i]); continue; };
    if (group["C"].length < percentile ) { group["C"].push(sortedArray[i]); continue; };
    if (group["D"].length < percentile ) { group["D"].push(sortedArray[i]); continue; };
    if (group["F"].length < percentile ) { group["F"].push(sortedArray[i]); continue; };
  };

  //Here you can return a specific grade to get the array, or the object and deal with it later
  return group["A"];

}
```